# Extracting data from OWL file

Tags: java, owl

```
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/vaio/ontologies/2013/0/untitled-ontology-113#hasDegree -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/vaio/ontologies/2013/0/untitled-ontology-113#hasDegree">

<rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/vaio/ontologies/2013/0/untitled-ontology-113#degree"/>

<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/vaio/ontologies/2013/0/untitled-ontology-113#student"/>

</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Using java api i need to check in `<owl:ObjectProperty` ,
if `rdf:about` then how I take `hasDegree` after the `#` and also  .. similarly if `rdfs:range` then `degree` after `#`

on the 6th line?

Or how can i extract these value using java api?

Comment: You can use XPath, or if you have xsd scheme you can try jaxb

Comment: I have a couple of examples on reasoning, persisting and parsing OWL with Jena in my GitHub, https://github.com/iferminm/ReasoningAndPersisting I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to get out of the file, your question is not clear.  But if you want to parse OWL, particularly OWL in RDF/XML format as you've shown, you should look at using either [Jena](http://jena.apache.org) or [Sesame](http://openrdf.org) as they are the defacto standard Java APIs for working with RDF.  I would recommend the Sesame API because it's simpler and easier to get the hang of, but both are very good libraries.

Each have good documentation on the website on how to use the API and active user & developer forums where you can seek help.

Good luck.

Comment: <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/vaio/ontologies/2013/0/untitled-ontology-113#hasDegree">                                                 how can i extract hasDegree from this and print "hasDegree" only using StringTokenizer in java

Comment: Update your question (or start a new question) if you are restricted to using only `StringTokenizer`, explaining why you have such a restriction...

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is in OWL, consider using the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/), or any other OWL API, rather than a less OWL-specific tool like XPath, XSLT, an RDF library, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) and that your questions is: "How do I get the ranges or domains of an object property in my ontology?" In that case:

```
/*Load the ontology from a local file and do the initialisations*/
File inputfile = new File("ontologyPath");
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(); ;
OWLDataFactory dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLOntology yourOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(inputfile);
IRI ontologyIRI = yourOntology.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI();  

/*Get an object property and its ranges*/  
OWLObjectProperty o_p_about = dataFactory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#"+"about"));
Set<OWLClassExpression> ranges_of_about = about.getRanges(LUCADAOntology);
```

To pick it up from here, you can check the documentation and example codes on the OWL-API webpage, they are very usfeul.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jena API to call the OWL file,then Turtle to write/output it.